# Rails API attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) arguments explained?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have decided to test out all methods in api.rubyonrails.org. I am starting with(no reason):

```
def attribute_missing(match, *args, &block)
  __send__(match.target, match.attr_name, *args, &block)
end
```

What data is this function expecting? Could someone give me a real-life example of this function with prepopulated arguments? I also need a way of testing each Rails Class instance method like #attribute_missing, with `"rails console"` command ? Many Thanks! I think this is the best way to go through the rails API and understand its functionality. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to this method can be explained as such:

`match`: The only required parameter for this method. Whoever is calling this method needs to at least provide the `match` parameter.

`*args`: `args` will contain all other arguments passed to this method. What this means is that calling `attribute_missing` with 5 arguments would result in `match` containing the first argument, and `args` being a 4-element array that contains the other arguments passed. The `*` is called the splat operator. Using the splat in method declaration will cause whatever parameter uses the splat (`args` in this case) to capture all other arguments passed to the method.

`&block`: If this method was passed a block, you can call it by using `block.call`.

I personally wouldn't recommend going through each and every method of the Rails API as a way to learn it. I would find a tutorial that can get you started writing an application using Rails, and then explore how functions work in the API as you use them.